# Can't boot Manjaro installer: failed to reset PPM

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro

New laptop. Trying to install manjaro but I see this message repeating when trying to boot into the installer:

```
failed to reset PPM!
PPM init failed (-110)
```

[image: can't boot]

Answer (score 0):

That error is because of a USB-C [driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/e7a1414f9dc3498c4c35b9ca266d539e8bccab53/drivers/usb/typec/ucsi/ucsi.c) (do you happen to have a new NVIDIA graphics card in that system?) and a bug report has been filled [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1850238). In the meantime you should still be able to boot anyway. If not, the cause may be somewhere else.